# PHP post ID of dropdown statement not value

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a PHP PDO statement that queries a table in my database to return a list of users.

The form is used to log maintenance events, so the username is used to log the person that has done the maintenance.

However when the form is submitted - its submitting the value of the dropdown box instead of the ID of the row it's returning. The table its submitting it into has a column "engineer" the is referencing the engineers table e.g. John Doe id = 1.

I think I need it to post the ID and not the name.. Here's my code:

```
  <form action="" method="post">
<label>Engineer Name:</label>
<br/><br/>
<select id="teamlist" name="teamlist">
 <?php
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=frontier_maintlog', 'user', 'pass');
        #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
        $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select name from engineers');
    $stmt->execute();
       while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['name'].'</option>';
       }
  ?>
 </select> 

<br/><br/>

<input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit"/><br />
</form>
```

and here's the bit that does the inserting into database:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO log (engineer, description, fa_description)
VALUES ('".$_POST["engineer"]."','".$_POST["description"]."','".$_POST["fa_description"]."')";
```

The "log" table looks a bit like this:[logtableimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq9Iu.png)

Thank you! Sorry if it doesn't make perfect sense.

Here's the error I receive `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'engineer' at row 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is that you are inserting string to int datatype.

You should also select `id` value from engineers table, to use for options:

```
...
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select id,name from engineers');
$stmt->execute();

// and assign value to options 
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
    echo "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[name]</option>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I didn't select the ID as well as the name.

Comment: Welcome, sometimes it happens. glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign a value to option. Every option needs to have it's own value. In you case you just echo the option.

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: You have to check what datatype is column "engineer" in your table.

Comment: Go in mysql and run "show create table engineers"  after that you can see what datatype is the column and change the column datatype or the post as your needs. What datatype is it?

Comment: Sorry i didnt see the image. What is the value of $_POST["engineer"]?